# Filling list of message for later display

Tags: message

I am calling various elisp functions (`h*`).  But because the functions can themselves call `message`, the messages  with `"+"` will be all over the place.  To keep them together, I could add the string to the list and print it later.  How can I implement this so that I always add `"+ frame"`, `"+ modust"`,
`"+ automode + speedbar"` to list for display later?

```
(hframe)
(message " + frame")

(hmodust)
(message " + modust")

(hautomode)
(hspeedbar)
(message " + automode + speedbar")
```

Had a go with

```
(defvar hcom '("typex-basic-launch Ignition"))

(setq hcom (append "+ modust-launch"))
(setq hcom (append "+ automode + speedbar"))
(setq hcom (append "+ modelin + txscale"))
```

But then

```
(message "%S" hcom)
```

did not print the contents of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps which just uses strings:

```el
(setq hcom "")
(setq hcom (concat hcom "+ modust-launch"))
(setq hcom (concat hcom "+ automode + speedbar"))
(setq hcom (concat hcom "+ modelin + txscale"))
(message "%s" hcom)
```

No need to worry about lists: you can just concatenate strings.

If you really want to do it with a list, I think something like this would work:

```el
(setq hcom nil)
(push "+ modust-launch" hcom)
(push "+ automode + speedbar" hcom)
(push "+ modelin + txscale" hcom)
(message "%s" (mapconcat #'identity (reverse hcom)))
```

`push` modifies its second argument (a list) by adding the first argument at the front of the list. It is equivalent to `(setq hcom (cons "foo" hcom))`. In both cases, you can push or cons arbitrary lisp objects, not just strings. The final processing reverses the list: we are pushing elements to the front of the list, so we need to process it back-to-front. The `mapconcat` applies a function to each element of the list; the function has to return a string and the results are concatenated. In this case, each element is already a string and the `identity` function returns each one unchanged.

I would recommend the "Introduction to Emacs Lisp" book that comes with your Emacs distribution: do `C-h i g(eintr)RET`. Read it from cover to cover.

Comment: There is also `add-to-list` and started doing `(add-to-list 'hcom "+ modust")`.

Comment: I do not append to a string because I want a newline between each string part.

Comment: There must be something wrong with `message` because it is not printing the list.

Comment: I doubt that very much: how are you trying to print it?

Comment: Exactly how you wrote it.  Except that initially I do `(defvar hcom '("basic"))`.

Comment: For the string case, `(concat hcom "foo" "\n")` will add a newline. `add-to-list` checks whether the element is already in the list. That is more expensive than `push`ing, but if you need uniqueness, it is indeed the way to go.

Comment: D'uh - I was missing the quotes. Edited.

Comment: No, I do not want to impose uniqueness.

Comment: Things are good now.